# Action of Z_5 in S^3

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology

Let $S^3 =\{ (x, y, z, w) \in \mathbb{R}^4: x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2=1\}$.

Let $G$ be a finite group and $E$ a topological space. We say that $G$ acts properly discontinuous in $E$ if $\forall x\in E$ exists $ U \subset E$ neighborhood of $x$ such that $gU \cap U = \emptyset \Leftrightarrow g \neq id$.

I need to find a properly discontinuous action of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ in $S^3$. I was thinking about consider $S^3 \subset \mathbb{C} \oplus \mathbb{C}$, but I don't know how to formalize this.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lens_space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Solve the problem on the circle $S^1$ first. Now can you generalize this solution?

Comment: Oh, I could see now how to do it. Thanks.